# ORACLE SQL - Determine, MAX value, when values could be alphanumeric-only or digits-only, and letters should be greater than digits

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, max

I want to determinate max value in Oracle, when values could be alphanumeric-only or digits-only.
Let say:

- **COLUMN_001**, with values
- **R**
- **BA**
- **4**
- **85**

When I use Oracle **MAX** function, like:

*SELECT MAX(T.COLUMN_002)
FROM TABLE_001 T;*

It returns me right now:

- **BA**

because:

- **4** < **85** < **R** < **BA**

what I wanted to have, is a function, for which letters will be greater than digits, like:

- **R** < **BA** < **4** < **85**

so below example, will returns me not **BA** but:

- **85**

Comment: What do you think about doing two queries using union, an SQL ordering numbers and other SQL ordering letters?

Comment: what is your question ? update your question with required output. At first you are saying it returns 'BA', then you saying it returning 85 but I want 'BA'. what exactly is your question ?

Comment: I've just extended my example, which editing. Example below is correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your original as:

```
select t.COLUMN_002
from (select t.COLUMN_002
      from TABLE_001 t
      order by t.COLUMN_002
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

With this version, you can change the `order by` and get any value you want:

```
select t.COLUMN_002
from (select t.COLUMN_002
      from TABLE_001 t
      order by (case when substr(t.COLUMN_002, 1, 1) between '0' and '9' then 1 else 2 end),
               t.COLUMN_002
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

If you don't like the subquery, you can also use the `KEEP` construct for this purpose.

Comment: It says me, that _ORA-00938: not enough arguments for function_. I see, that **substr** should have 3 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
select string from
(
select rank () over (partition by case order by string desc) rnk,string,case 
from
(select case  when substr(string,1,1) between '0' and '9' then 1 else 2 end case ,string
from ex_b
order by string desc) tbl
) tbl_1
where rnk = 1
and case = 1

This query will give the desired result
Regards,
```